# Javascript trick for 'paste as plain text` in execCommand

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, execcommand

I have a basic editor based on `execCommand` following the sample introduced here. There are three ways to paste text within the `execCommand` area:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- Right Click -> Paste
- Right Click -> Paste As Plain Text

I want to allow pasting only plain text without any HTML markup. How can I force the first two actions to paste Plain Text?

**Possible Solution:** The way I can think of is to set listener for keyup events for (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) and strip HTML tags before paste.

1. Is it the best solution?
2. Is it bulletproof to avoid any HTML markup in paste?
3. How to add listener to Right Click -> Paste?

Comment: As a side note, do you also want to take care of text being dragged into the editor? That is another way HTML can leak into the editor.

Comment: @pimvdb You answer was enough for my need. Just out of curiosity, is there a simple method to avoid dragged leakage too?

Comment: I thought this would do the job: http://jsfiddle.net/HBEzc/2/. But on Chrome at least, the text is always inserted at the beginning of the editor, unfortunately.

Comment: You need to use clipboard api as explaiend here.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q81HH2Od5oo

Answer (score 301, accepted):

It will intercept the `paste` event, cancel the `paste`, and manually insert the text representation of the clipboard:
http://jsfiddle.net/HBEzc/. 
This should be the most reliable:

- It catches all kinds of pasting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, context menu, etc.)
- It allows you to get the clipboard data directly as text, so you don't have to do ugly hacks to replace HTML.

I'm not sure of cross-browser support, though.

```
editor.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
    // cancel paste
    e.preventDefault();

    // get text representation of clipboard
    var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

    // insert text manually
    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, text);
});
```

Comment: @Ali: I missed something obvious. If `text` contains HTML (e.g. if you copy HTML code as plain text) then it will actually paste it as HTML. Here's a solution to it, but it's not very pretty: http://jsfiddle.net/HBEzc/3/.

Comment: This does not work in Chrome/Chromium: clipboardData.getData comes back as empty

Comment: from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser there is a similar solution that is claimed to work in IE (8,9,10 and 11), it uses getData("text") instead of getData("text/plain")

Comment: `var text = (event.originalEvent || event).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');` provides a bit more cross-browser compatibility

Comment: this is a great code snippet. text area in WebKit doesn't has a bug where pasting 'large' amounts of data is extremely slow. This code makes it work as it should. thanks!

Comment: This breaks the undo functionality. (Ctrl+Z)

Comment: Great solution, but this diverges from the default behavior. If the user copies something like `<div></div>` that content will be added as a child element of the contenteditable element. I fixed it like this: `document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);`

Comment: It replaces new lines with nothing. Hence all new lines are vanished.

Comment: I found `insertHTML` and `insertText` don't work in IE11, however `document.execCommand('paste', false, text);` works just fine. Although that then doesn't seem to work in other browsers >_>.

Comment: Jamie Barker's answer it's the correct one as it provides support for IE11

Comment: both `insertHTML` and `insertText` don't work in firefox (within textarea)

Comment: @paradite please see my BUG-ticket https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1220696

Comment: @webprogrammer thanks. I coded a fix for `textarea` here: https://gist.github.com/paradite/f66862dbfb61001c8dd09680747eec06 using `value`, `selectionStart ` and `selectionEnd ` attributes.

Comment: This doesn't preserve newlines

Comment: Use `return false;` instead of `e.preventDefault();` to keep `undo` (Ctrl+Z) working

Comment: `execCommand` is now [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Comment: Great answer and was very helpful :) Copying and pasting something like `<h4>hello world</h4>`   this will break it though

Comment: 'document.execCommand' is deprecated

Comment: @Oleg No, that literally does nothing good. Your `return false;` instead of `e.preventDefault();` proposal just makes pasting paste the data twice (original + modified) and undoing only undoes the original data.

Answer (score 49):

I couldn't get the accepted answer here to work in IE so I did some scouting around and came to this answer which works in IE11 and the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('paste', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = '';
    if (e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
      text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    } else if (window.clipboardData) {
      text = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    }
    if (document.queryCommandSupported('insertText')) {
      document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
    } else {
      document.execCommand('paste', false, text);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i was truggling with that same issue... insertText wasn't working on neither IE11 nor latest FF :)

Comment: Is it possible that it in some cases pastes the text twice in both Firefox and Chrome? Seems to me..

Comment: @Fanky I didn't have that issue when I created it, however I no longer work at the place where I created this code so I couldn't tell you if it still works! Could you describe how it's pasting twice?

Comment: @Fanky See if you can re-create it on here: https://jsfiddle.net/v2qbp829/.

Comment: I cannot paste in the box at the fiddle..does nothing - in FF 47.0.1

Comment: @Fanky What browser and version are you using?

Comment: Seems now that the problem I had was due to calling your script from a file which was itself loaded by a script. I can't paste into neither textarea nor input in your fiddle in FF 47.0.1 (can do it in chrome), but can paste into div contenteditable, which is key for me. Thanks!

Comment: @PascalLindelauf I rolled back your edit because my answer does not target IE10. [Microsoft do no support it themselves](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support) so I refuse also to put any code out into the wild that suggests you should support it, because quite frankly you shouldn't. You're basically telling people it is okay to be using a browser that is a security risk.

Comment: This seems to work in IE11 at the first glance only. Actually IE reports a "Stack overflow" error. This can easily observed in the above fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v2qbp829

Comment: @dpr Right at this very moment (30/01/2018 10:45am GMT) it looks like JSFiddle isn't working in IE at all for any fiddles. Just to be sure I've [created a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MQYyBX) with the same code and it's seemingly working fine in IE there.

Comment: @JamieBarker, if you open the dev console in IE, you will notice the stack overflow error, in the code pen as well. Without the console it looks like it's working, but actually it's producing an error.

Comment: @dpr So there is. It appears to be working correctly while producing the console error at least. See if you can work out how to fix it if you like ;)

Comment: Use `return false;` instead of `e.preventDefault();` to keep `undo` (Ctrl+Z) working

Answer (score 23):

A close solution as pimvdb. But it's working of FF, Chrome and IE 9:

```
editor.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.clipboardData) {
        content = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

        document.execCommand('insertText', false, content);
    }
    else if (window.clipboardData) {
        content = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');

        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(content);
    }   
});
```

Comment: I like the short-circuit `content` variable assignment. I have found that using `getData('Text')` works cross-browser, so you could make that assignment just once like this: `var content = ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('Text');` Then you'd only have to use logic for cross-browser paste/insert command.

Comment: I don't think you can write `document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(content)`... just tested on IE11 and it doesn't work like that.

Comment: `document.execCommand('insertText', false, content)` does not work as of IE11 and Edge. Also, latest versions of Chrome now support `document.execCommand('paste', false, content)`, which is simpler. They might be deprecating `insertText`.

Answer (score 19):

Of course the question is already answered and the topic very old but I want to provide my solution as it is simple an clean:

This is inside my paste-event on my contenteditable-div.

```
var text = '';
var that = $(this);

if (e.clipboardData)
    text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
else if (window.clipboardData)
    text = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
else if (e.originalEvent.clipboardData)
    text = $('<div></div>').text(e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text'));

if (document.queryCommandSupported('insertText')) {
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, $(text).html());
    return false;
}
else { // IE > 7
    that.find('*').each(function () {
         $(this).addClass('within');
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
          // nochmal alle durchlaufen
          that.find('*').each(function () {
               // wenn das element keine klasse 'within' hat, dann unwrap
               // http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/
               $(this).not('.within').contents().unwrap();
          });
    }, 1);
}
```

The else-part is from another SO-post I couldn't find anymore...

---

UPDATE 19.11.2014:
[The other SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257688/paste-rich-text-into-content-editable-div-and-only-keep-bold-and-italics-formatt)

Comment: I think you are referring to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257688/paste-rich-text-into-content-editable-div-and-only-keep-bold-and-italics-formatt

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me in Safari. Maybe something is wrong

Answer (score 9):

None of the posted answers really seems to work cross browser or the solution is over complicated:

- The command `insertText` is not supported by IE
- Using the `paste` command results in stack overflow error in IE11

What worked for me (IE11, Edge, Chrome and FF) is the following:

```js
$("div[contenteditable=true]").off('paste').on('paste', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData ? e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain') : window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    _insertText(text);
});

function _insertText(text) { 
    // use insertText command if supported
    if (document.queryCommandSupported('insertText')) {
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
    }
    // or insert the text content at the caret's current position
    // replacing eventually selected content
    else {
        var range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
        range.insertNode(textNode);
        range.selectNodeContents(textNode);
        range.collapse(false);

        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<textarea name="t1"></textarea>
<div style="border: 1px solid;" contenteditable="true">Edit me!</div>
<input />
</body>
```

Note that the custom paste handler is only needed/working for `contenteditable` nodes. As both `textarea` and plain `input` fields don't support pasting HTML content at all, so nothing needs to be done here.

Comment: I had to get rid of `.originalEvent` in the event handler (line 3) to get this to work. So the complete line looks like this: `const text = ev.clipboardData ? ev.clipboardData.getData('text/plain') : window.clipboardData.getData('Text');`. Works in latest Chrome, Safari, Firefox.

Comment: need to replace `var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData ? e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain') : window.clipboardData.getData('Text');` with `var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');`

Answer (score 5):

Note that `execCommand()` is deprecated, so avoid using it in your production environments. Do something like this instead:

```js
const editor = document.querySelector('[contentEditable]')
editor.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste)

function handlePaste(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  const text = (e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text')
  const selection = window.getSelection()

  if (selection.rangeCount) {
    selection.deleteFromDocument()
    selection.getRangeAt(0).insertNode(document.createTextNode(text))
  }
}
```

```css
[contentEditable] {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable>Paste HTML here</div>
```

#### References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event

Comment: It's worth noting that this does not let the browser record the history of changes which means the user wouldn't be able to CTRL+Z the pasted text.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox does not allow you to access the clipboard data so you'll need to make a 'hack' to get it to work. I've not been able to find a complete solution, however you can fix it for ctrl+v pastes by creating a textarea & pasting to that instead:

```
//Test if browser has the clipboard object
if (!window.Clipboard)
{
    /*Create a text area element to hold your pasted text
    Textarea is a good choice as it will make anything added to it in to plain text*/           
    var paster = document.createElement("textarea");
    //Hide the textarea
    paster.style.display = "none";              
    document.body.appendChild(paster);
    //Add a new keydown event tou your editor
    editor.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){

        function handlePaste()
        {
            //Get the text from the textarea
            var pastedText = paster.value;
            //Move the cursor back to the editor
            editor.focus();
            //Check that there is a value. FF throws an error for insertHTML with an empty string
            if (pastedText !== "") document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, pastedText);
            //Reset the textarea
            paster.value = "";
        }

        if (e.which === 86 && e.ctrlKey)
        {
            //ctrl+v => paste
            //Set the focus on your textarea
            paster.focus();
            //We need to wait a bit, otherwise FF will still try to paste in the editor => settimeout
            window.setTimeout(handlePaste, 1);
        }

    }, false);
}
else //Pretty much the answer given by pimvdb above
{
    //Add listener for paster to force paste-as-plain-text
    editor.addEventListener("paste", function(e){

        //Get the plain text from the clipboard
        var plain = (!!e.clipboardData)? e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain") : window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
            //Stop default paste action
        e.preventDefault();
        //Paste plain text
        document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, plain);

    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also working on a plain text paste and I started to hate all the execCommand and getData errors, so I decided to do it the classic way and it works like a charm:

```
$('#editor').bind('paste', function(){
    var before = document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML;
    setTimeout(function(){
        var after = document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML;
        var pos1 = -1;
        var pos2 = -1;
        for (var i=0; i<after.length; i++) {
            if (pos1 == -1 && before.substr(i, 1) != after.substr(i, 1)) pos1 = i;
            if (pos2 == -1 && before.substr(before.length-i-1, 1) != after.substr(after.length-i-1, 1)) pos2 = i;
        }
        var pasted = after.substr(pos1, after.length-pos2-pos1);
        var replace = pasted.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
        var replaced = after.substr(0, pos1)+replace+after.substr(pos1+pasted.length);
        document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML = replaced;
    }, 100);
});
```

The code with my notations can be found here:
http://www.albertmartin.de/blog/code.php/20/plain-text-paste-with-javascript

Answer (score 2):

In 2022, you can use CSS user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only to archive this

```
.plain-text-only {
  user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
  -moz-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}

div[contenteditable] {
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
<div contenteditable class="plain-text-only">Can't paste HTML here</div>
<div contenteditable>HTML styled text free</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be deprecated..

Answer (score 1):

```
function PasteString() {
    var editor = document.getElementById("TemplateSubPage");
    editor.focus();
  //  editor.select();
    document.execCommand('Paste');
}

function CopyString() {
    var input = document.getElementById("TemplateSubPage");
    input.focus();
   // input.select();
    document.execCommand('Copy');
    if (document.selection || document.textSelection) {
        document.selection.empty();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
}
```

Above code works for me in IE10 and IE11 and now also works in Chrome and Safari. Not tested in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

In IE11, execCommand doesn't work well. I use below code for IE11
`<div class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-md" contenteditable=true>`
is my div box.

I read clipboard data from window.clipboardData and modify div's textContent and give caret.

I give timeout for setting caret, because if I don't set timeout, a caret goes to end of div.

and you should read clipboardData in IE11 in below way. If you don't do it, newline caracter is not handled properly, so caret goes wrong.

```
var tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
tempDiv.textContent = window.clipboardData.getData("text");
var text = tempDiv.textContent;
```

Tested on IE11 and chrome. It may not work on IE9

```
document.getElementById("wmd-input-md").addEventListener("paste", function (e) {
    if (!e.clipboardData) {
        //For IE11
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
        tempDiv.textContent = window.clipboardData.getData("text");
        var text = tempDiv.textContent;
        var selection = document.getSelection();
        var start = selection.anchorOffset > selection.focusOffset ? selection.focusOffset : selection.anchorOffset;
        var end = selection.anchorOffset > selection.focusOffset ? selection.anchorOffset : selection.focusOffset;                    
        selection.removeAllRanges();

        setTimeout(function () {    
            $(".wmd-input").text($(".wmd-input").text().substring(0, start)
              + text
              + $(".wmd-input").text().substring(end));
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(document.getElementsByClassName("wmd-input")[0].firstChild, start + text.length);
            range.setEnd(document.getElementsByClassName("wmd-input")[0].firstChild, start + text.length);

            selection.addRange(range);
        }, 1);
    } else {                
        //For Chrome
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = e.clipboardData.getData("text");

        var selection = document.getSelection();
        var start = selection.anchorOffset > selection.focusOffset ? selection.focusOffset : selection.anchorOffset;
        var end = selection.anchorOffset > selection.focusOffset ? selection.anchorOffset : selection.focusOffset;

        $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0, start)
          + text
          + $(this).text().substring(end));

        var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart($(this)[0].firstChild, start + text.length);
        range.setEnd($(this)[0].firstChild, start + text.length);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

After along search and trying I have found somehow kind of optimal solution

> what is important to keep in mind

```
// /\x0D/g return key ASCII
window.document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, text.replace('/\x0D/g', "\\n"))


and give the css style white-space: pre-line //for displaying
```

```js
var contenteditable = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]')
            contenteditable.addEventListener('paste', function(e){
                let text = ''
                contenteditable.classList.remove('empty')                
                e.preventDefault()
                text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
                e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', '')                 
                window.document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, text.replace('/\x0D/g', "\\n"))// /\x0D/g return ASCII
        })
```

```css
#input{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: pre-line; 
}
```

```html
<div id="input"contenteditable="true">
        <p>
        </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK as everybody is trying to work around clipboard data, checking keypress event, and using execCommand.

I thought of this

CODE

```js
handlePastEvent=()=>{
    document.querySelector("#new-task-content-1").addEventListener("paste",function(e)
    {
        
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.querySelector("#new-task-content-1").innerHTML=document.querySelector("#new-task-content-1").innerText.trim();
        },1);
    });

}
handlePastEvent();
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="new-task-content-1">You cann't paste HTML here</div>
```

Comment: But the formatting of the text should be removed too.

Comment: It's a bad idea in so many ways