# Paste rich text into content-editable div and only keep bold and italics formatting

Tags: jquery, html

I want to paste some rich text which has different fonts, font sizes, font weights, etc. into a content-editable `div` and ONLY keep boldness and italics. Any idea how to go about this?

The following code turns rich text into plain text when pasted into content-editable div.

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain') || prompt('Paste something..');
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
});
```

I've tried looking at the `text` variable in the above code, but it doesn't seem to be formatted.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SJR3H/7/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('[contenteditable]').on('paste',function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/html') || prompt('Paste something..');
            var $result = $('<div></div>').append($(text));

            $(this).html($result.html());

            // replace all styles except bold and italic
            $.each($(this).find("*"), function(idx, val) {

                var $item = $(val);
                if ($item.length > 0){
                   var saveStyle = {
                        'font-weight': $item.css('font-weight'),
                        'font-style': $item.css('font-style')
                    };
                    $item.removeAttr('style')
                         .removeClass()
                         .css(saveStyle); 
                }
            });

            // remove unnecesary tags (if paste from word)
            $(this).children('style').remove();
            $(this).children('meta').remove()
            $(this).children('link').remove();

        });

    });
```

**Later edit:** http://jsfiddle.net/SJR3H/8/

i added the following lines:

```
$item.replaceWith(function(){
       return $("<span />", {html: $(this).html()});
});
```

It actually replaces all `html` tags with `span`s. There you can optionally choose to let some tags as they were in the original text (`h1`, `p`, etc), styling them as you desire.

Comment: Hey Cristi, this doesn't seem to work in some cases. I tried copying part of a wikipedia article (with <h2> tags etc.) and the formatting and underlying html structure remained. Any idea how to fix this? I don't need this any more, but by the looks of it, it would help a heap of others!

Comment: This is really close! I think a lot of people could work it out from here - it's just that superscripts, links, and a few other things persist. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Let begin with your code :

```
//on paste
var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain')


//html in clipboard are saved as Plain Unicode string , 

getData('text/plain') //return data as string,

//if MIME TYPE 'text/html' is used you will get data as html with style attributes

// insert text

document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);

//this will simply insert the text to contenteditable div.

//so there is no chance of knowing recieved text is bold / italics.
```

(1) we must get data as html,to get style properties: fontWeight, fontStyle.

(2) reduce html for needed style format,

(3) append to contenteditable div.

!important ::

we depend on Clipboard API, to get data.

it is not fully supported by newer browsers, please check links below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/paste

http://caniuse.com/clipboard

so in IE Browser it wont work as expected.

the data format argument we pass in getData() is different in IE Browser:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536436(v=vs.85).aspx

so we get only plain string from getData() method,
i checked in IE 9.0.8112.16421 ( not updated ) ,

i am not aware of version IE 10, 11.

I coded in a way,
if getData("Html") supported in ie 10,11 code, requirements will get done.

Code works :
Like @Cristi did, get all html elements.

iterate through them, instead of changing style attributes  we use tags.

tags for bold &  tag for italics.

Iterations are done asynchronously, 
because pasting large text content may hang browser.

I had Tested in Chrome, Firefox.

```
pasteArea.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {

    // prevent pasting text by default after event
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var clipboardData = {},
    rDataText,
    rDataHTML;

    clipboardData = e.clipboardData;
    rDataHTML = clipboardData.getData('text/html');
    rDataPText = clipboardData.getData('text/plain');


    if (rDataHTML && rDataHTML.trim().length != 0) {

        //Function Call to Handle HTML

        return false; // prevent returning text in clipboard
    }

    if (rDataPText && rDataPText.trim().length != 0) {

        //Function Call to Handle Plain String

        return false; // prevent returning text in clipboard
    }

}, false);

// Handle Plain Text
function PlainTextHandler(pText) {
    // Remove Line breaks
    // append to contenteditable div - using range.insertNode()
    // document.execCommand();  had issue in ie9 so i didn't used it 
}

// Handle HTML
function formatHtml(elem, complete) {
        var flag_italic = false;
        var flag_weight = false;
        var fontStyle;
        var fontWeight;

        if (elem.nodeType == 1) { // only pass html elements

            // get style in css 
            var CSSStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem);
            fontStyle = CSSStyle.fontStyle;
            fontWeight = CSSStyle.fontWeight;

            // get style defined by inline
            var InlineStyle = elem.style;
            inlineFontStyle = InlineStyle['font-style'];
            inlineFontWeight = InlineStyle['font-weight'];
            if (inlineFontStyle && inlineFontStyle.trim() != '') fontStyle = inlineFontStyle;
            if (inlineFontWeight && inlineFontWeight.trim() != '') fontWeight = inlineFontWeight;

            // get style defined in MSword
            var msStyle = elem.getAttribute('style');
            if (/mso-bidi/.test(msStyle)) {
                var MSStyleObj = {};
                var styleStrArr = msStyle.split(";");
                for (i = 0; i < styleStrArr.length; i++) {
                    var temp = styleStrArr[i].split(":");
                    MSStyleObj[temp[0]] = temp[1];
                }
                fontStyle = MSStyleObj['mso-bidi-font-style'];
                fontWeight = MSStyleObj['mso-bidi-font-weight'];
            }

            if (fontStyle && fontStyle == 'italic') flag_italic = true; // flag true if italic

            if (fontWeight && (fontWeight == 'bold' || 600 <= (+fontWeight))) flag_weight = true;  // flag true if bold - 600 is semi bold

            // bold & italic are not applied via style
            // these styles are applied by appending contents in new tags string & bold
            if (flag_italic && flag_weight) {
                var strong = document.createElement('strong');
                var italic = document.createElement('i');
                strong.appendChild(italic);
                newtag = strong;
            } else {
                if (flag_italic) {
                    newtag = document.createElement('i');
                } else if (flag_weight) {
                    newtag = document.createElement('strong');
                } else {
                    // remove un wanted attributes & element
                    var tagName = elem.tagName;
                    // strong are not skipped because, by creating new unwanted attributes will be removed
                    if (tagName == 'STRONG' || tagName == 'B') {
                        newtag = document.createElement('strong');
                    } else if (tagName == 'I') {
                        newtag = document.createElement('i');
                    } else {
                        newtag = document.createElement('span');
                    }
                }
            }

            // content appended
            var elemHTML = elem.innerHTML;
            if (flag_italic && flag_weight) {
                newtag.childNodes[0].innerHTML = elemHTML;
            } else {
                newtag.innerHTML = elemHTML;
            }

            // curr element is replaced by new
            elem.parentNode.insertBefore(newtag, elem);
            elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        }
        complete() // completed one iteration
    }
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/d9cfF/7/

Answer (score 3):

I used this on my website for long time

```
$(document).on('paste','#tesc', function() {
                 setTimeout(function() {
                        asd = strip_tags( $('#tesc').html(), '<b><b/><i></i>');

                        $('#tesc').html( asd );
                },100);

        });

function strip_tags (input, allowed) {
    /* http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net*/

    if ( input == undefined ) { return ''; }

    allowed = (((allowed || "") + "").toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
    var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
        commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
    return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function ($0, $1) {
        return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
    });
}
```