# How to keep text formatting in HTML Input Form?

Tags: python, html, input, bold, italic

I have an input field in the html form. When I paste a text in that field, I don't want the text's bold, underline and italic attribute to be lost. I want to use the style info too in the backend.

So how do I exactly go about preserving the style attributes in an html input text field ?

Thanks in advance : )

Comment: I hope this helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257688/paste-rich-text-into-content-editable-div-and-only-keep-bold-and-italics-formatt

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with html input field. 
You need a richtextbox/editor.

I find a source like following, hope to help you: 
https://www.learnpyqt.com/examples/megasolid-idiom-rich-text-editor/