# javascript how to paste "as plain text" in multiple fields or elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to paste text into multiple fields, but the formatting is only cleared on the first element, not the second etc.

I found this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/12028136/3955607 which works fine, but again, on multiple elements it doesnt work.

So I got this HTML

```
<div style="color:red">Some <em>rich</em> <span style="font-size:2em">HTML</span></div>
<br />
<div style="border:1px solid red" contenteditable></div>
<br />
<div style="border:1px solid red" contenteditable></div>
```

and this javascript:

```
document.querySelector("div[contenteditable]").addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var text = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
   document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, text);
});
```

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tdjuc8es/

just copy and paste the `Some rich HTML`- text and see what happens

Someone who can help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.querySelector` yields one element. You want to use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all matching elements, and then iterate over that collection.

```
var editors = document.querySelectorAll('div[contenteditable]');
for(var i = 0, l = editors.length; i < l; i++) {
   editors[i].addEventListener('paste', myCustomPasteFunction);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfgveq5f/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're used to jQuery, you might think that `document.querySelector()` fulfils the same kind of function; however, it only returns the first element that matches the selector; instead you should have used `document.querySelectorAll()` and then used iteration to add your event handlers.

Since you've tagged it as [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), you could also consider this:

```js
$("div[contenteditable]").on("paste", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
   document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, text);
});
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="color:blue">Some <em>rich</em> <span style="font-size:2em">HTML</span></div>
<br />
<div style="border:1px solid red" contenteditable></div>
<br />
<div style="border:1px solid red" contenteditable></div>
```

I'm using `e.originalEvent` here because the one that jQuery passes you in the event handler is a wrapper object.

Answer (score 1):

It is beacause the `document.querySelector` only return the first matched element.
You can use `document.querySelectorAll` instated.

Wish it can help you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.This post might answer the question.But a little more explanation might help out the fellow programmers to understand how it works.