# Allow only text to be pasted in a content editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple text editor in which i used the content editable div as shown below:

```
<div contentEditable=true id = "message"></div>
```

Now, what I want is to disable pasting of styled texts or images - what i mean here is that I just wanted to allow only **simple text**.

Another option is to remove all the html dom, style and also images from the pasted text and just let the simple text remain (without style). Which is i think more complicated than the first one.

Please also take a look at this image i provided:

[image]

As you can see it allows images to be pasted and also text colors, text sizes and etc. What I want is just a simple text only.

I know it is possible but I don't know how to implement it. I'm just beginning to learn simple javascript and don't know it's other capabilities yet.
I hope you can help me with this one guys, I'm very desperate. Many thanks

-Wendell

Comment: *Simple text* is ASCII or unicode *Simple Text*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6804718/859154

Comment: check on KeyPress event that ASCII code for key that is text or not. you can do that in this simple maner

Comment: Also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12028136/5247200

Comment: Thanks to you guys.. Tried to find question similar to this one but I guess i'm not lucky to find but now i have many many sources. Thanks! :)