# IE11 drop plain text into contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-11, contenteditable

I have a div that is `contenteditable` but I don't want to allow users to paste or drop formatted content into the div as this will - very likely - break the layout of the page.

The question how to handle HTML content that is **pasted** into such a div has already been raised several times and I was able to solve this problem as described here:

[Javascript trick for 'paste as plain text` in execCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027137/javascript-trick-for-paste-as-plain-text-in-execcommand/48502897#48502897)

In one of the comments of the above question the point was raised that - in order to avoid HTML formatted content in the div at all - one needs to handle dropped content as well.

I need to support FF, Chrome, Edge and IE11. For all but IE11 I was able to implement a custom drop handler:

```js
$("div[contenteditable=true]").on('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.types.indexOf && e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.types.indexOf('text/plain') >= 0 ? e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain') :  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
    var range;
    if (!document.caretRangeFromPoint) { // IE11 doesn't support caretRangeFromPoint
        range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(e.currentTarget, 0);
        range.setEnd(e.currentTarget, 0);
    } else {
        range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.originalEvent.clientX, e.originalEvent.clientY);
    }
    _insertText(text, range);
});

function _insertText(text, range) { 
    range.deleteContents();
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
    range.insertNode(textNode);
    range.selectNodeContents(textNode);
    range.collapse(false);

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h4 style="color:red">Drag Me</h4>
<div style="border: 1px solid;" contenteditable="true">Drop here</div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m25z6ch6/

As IE11 doesn't support `document.caretRangeFromPoint` I already tried to manually create a range as can be seen in the above snippet like this:

```
range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(e.currentTarget, 0);
range.setEnd(e.currentTarget, 0);
```

But This only works for dropping the content at the start of the already existing text. If I want to drop content into already existing text (e.g. between "Drop" and "here" in the above example), I somehow need to compute the offset to use. But I can't figure out how to do this for IE.

Is there a way to create a range object with correct offset given the information in a drop event (e.g. x,y coordinates and/or drop target element)?

Or is there any other way to customize the dropped content in order to allow plain text only for IE11?

Comment: I just noticed that the above snippet is not working for recent FF anymore although implemented according to documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/document/caretRangeFromPoint However the question remains the same

Comment: `Drop` from where  ?`Contenteditable`...?

Comment: @NikhilGhuse have a look at the fiddle. Try to drag the text that says “drag me” into the contenteditable.