# document.execCommand("paste") doesn't work - return false

Tags: javascript, firefox, execcommand

I want to execute the command:

```
document.execCommand("paste");
```

on Javascript. But it always returns only false!
The `console.log` in the example below shows the text "false"!

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = () => {
  document.querySelector("input").focus();
  console.log("execCommand('paste') returns", document.execCommand("paste"));
};
```

```html
<button>paste</button>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not generally allow web pages to access the clipboard, as it may contain sensitive information - per [MDN docs for execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand):

> **`paste`** - Pastes the clipboard contents at the insertion point (replaces current selection). **Disabled for web content.**

An exception to this rule is when the user explicitly pastes data into your web page (via CTRL/Cmd+V or the context menu) - then you can access the clipboard contents in the `paste` event listener, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12028136/1026 for details.